# How to build exe in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am a .NET C# developer and trying to learn C++.

I am having issues in trying to create an exe from a console app from Microsoft Visual Studio when I do a build compile and check the Debug folder. There isn't any exe, just some manifest files and other files. I am asking this because I am not sure if this is how it works? is there any another way of doing this?

I have tried the Microsoft Visual Studio console and c:\cl test.cpp, this gives me an test.exe but can it be done from the MSVS GUI like in C#?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have you checked the debug folder at the solution level? I believe this is the default target directory. The DEBUG folder in the project is for the output of temporary build files.

Comment: ty mate that was it, the files goes in the DEBUG folder on the project level in C# so i got confused.

Answer (score 2):

Did it compile successfully ?  Also, check your active configuration if its debug or Release ?

Also, check the output path to double check the location of executable.

It works the same as C#, so there is no need for command line.